# A matlab code to generate this figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
jan             0.23%
feb             2.56%
mar             0.76%
apr             4.19% <-- This is the highest value
may            -0.36%
jun            -1.68% <-- This is the lowest value
jul             1.18%
aug            -0.99%
sep            -1.43%
nov             2.32%
dec             1.88%
```

What code can generate exactly the figure above without apostrophe and without being too complicated. Using for loops maybe? Note that the color of all letters and numbers is black.
I tried the following code :

C={'jan' 0.23 ' ';'feb' 2.56 ' ';'mar' 0.72 ' ';'apr' 4.19 '<-- This is the highest value';'may' -0.36 ' ';'jun' -1.68 '<-- This is the lowest value';'jul' 1.18 ' ';'aug' -0.99 ' ';'sep' -1.43 ' ';'oct' 2.00 ' ';'nov' 2.32 ' ';'dec' 1.88 ' '}
And i got this

```
'jan'    [ 0.2300]    ' '                       
'feb'    [ 2.5600]    ' '                       
'mar'    [ 0.7200]    ' '                       
'apr'    [ 4.1900]    '<-- This is the highes…'
'may'    [-0.3600]    ' '                       
'jun'    [-1.6800]    '<-- This is the lowest…'
'jul'    [ 1.1800]    ' '                       
'aug'    [-0.9900]    ' '                       
'sep'    [-1.4300]    ' '                       
'oct'    [      2]    ' '                       
'nov'    [ 2.3200]    ' '                       
'dec'    [ 1.8800]    ' '
```

But it's not even close to what i want, it is very incomplete, contains apostrophes and so.

Comment: What did you try ? What is the exact problem you are facing ? Show some code.

Comment: I edited my post so you now you can see what i tried to do. The problem that I'm facing is that I can't figure out exactly how to write a code that generates exactly the same figure as the first one, clean and tidy. What I got is very messy and contains a lot of unwanted and incomplete stuffs like apostrophes, and the missing percent symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to find max and min value in second columns. 
Then try using ``printf()'' to print out the columns, at the max and min index print the text. 
Sorry, i'm using mobile so I can't write the answer in detail.

Comment: I can't use my laptop until tomorrow evening. You can trying following steps. 
1. Create 2 array for month and corresponding values. 
2. Get indexs of max and min in value array. 
3. Use a for loop with index to print out  month and value. If index is equal to index of max or min value, just print additional text you want.